# Facebook Like Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible to request the likes of a particular object for a specific time? I have to know the likes till 2011-09-30.

Like:

```
SELECT url, share_count, like_count,
       comment_count, click_count, total_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url="'.$url.' and date <= '2011-09-30'"
```

Are there any date columns in the link_stat table?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/), no there are not.  Personally I would be very surprised if Facebook maintained this information.  It's a lot more efficient to just store the aggregate count than to maintain a distinct row for each 'like' that occurs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they store all likes and timestamp, though this is not available for the API, aggregate tables are a lot more efficient for selects - this is correct but that doesn't contradict the need to store everything.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of info is not available via facebook API but you can maintain it in your database, simply make a call every day and store it in your database and you will have historical info, build graphs for your objects, etc.

Also if your object is a page, application or domain you can check insights:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

which will give you relevant info